# How to access android file system in a meteor app?

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I have some experience with meteorJS developing web apps but am just getting started with Cordova/hybrid app development.  How would one access the android file system in a meteor app? 
Like if I wanted to display a list of pictures or media files on the device to the user in a meteor template, how could I get those files or the path to those files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298124/list-files-inside-www-folder-in-phonegap

Comment: That answers the question of how to read the files. But I would like to know how to pull the files into meteor?

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the answer from [List files inside www folder in PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298124/list-files-inside-www-folder-in-phonegap) for meteor:

```
if (Meteor.isCordova) {
Meteor.startup(function () {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory("Download", {
            create: true
        }, function(directory) {

            var directoryReader = directory.createReader();
            directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
                var i;
                for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
                    console.log(entries[i].name);
                    var fileName = (entries[i].name);
                    var fullPath = (entries[i].fullPath);
                    var fileItem = {
                        name: fileName,
                        path: fullPath
                    };
                    Files.insert(fileItem);  // inserts files into a mongo collection named "Files"
                }

            }, function (error) {
                alert(error.code);
            });

        } );
    }, function(error) {
        alert("can't even get the file system: " + error.code);
    });
});
```

}

Comment: This will get image meta data like the file name and path, but I can't load the actual image. I've tried putting the path into <img src={{path}} />, but the images won't load.